# GCC- Invalid use of Register

Tags: c++, c, gcc, codeblocks

I am compiling a project under VS2012 and GCC (CodeBlocks) for Windows.
On VS2012 everything works perfect. Under GCC I am obtaining the following compiling error:

```
C:\Users\Piotrek\AppData\Local\Temp\ccfdl0Ye.s|164|Error: invalid use of register|
C:\Users\Piotrek\AppData\Local\Temp\ccfdl0Ye.s|166|Error: invalid use of register|
C:\Users\Piotrek\AppData\Local\Temp\ccfdl0Ye.s|221|Error: invalid use of register|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 14 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

I am using the compiler option -fpermissive - It should have nothing to do with the error.

I just can't understand why is it pointing to a temporary file under the Local Temp folder, and saying that I am using a wrong register??

Does anybody have any idea on what's happening?

Comment: GCC is actually not a single program, it's a set of programs all run one after another. First there is the preprocessor, then there's the actual compiler, the compiler generates assembler code which is fed to the assembler, which generates object files used by the linker to create the final executable. The file mentioned in the error message is the generated assembler file. While this doesn't help much with your problem, I hope it explains why you have these temporary files.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Looks more like a compiler bug to me.  Warnings indicate *potential* semantic errors but if an error is generated by the assembler, it probably indicates a flaw in the compiler.

Comment: My second best bet is that there's a mismatch in flags given to assembler and compiler -- that is one generates code e.g. for SSE and one expects legacy x86 instruction set. My best bet is that the code contains asm directive, which is VS2012 is in Intel syntax while gcc expects AT&T. asm directives are passed as is to 'as' stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've encountered a bug in the compiler.  The
error messages (judging from the "source" file name) are from
the assembler.  The only time the assembler should generate an
error message is when there is something illegal in the
assembler, and the C++ compiler should *never* generate illegal
assembler; if it can't generate legal assembler, it should
output an error message and fail.

The real problem, when you get this sort of message, is to
figure out what in your code is triggering it.  g++ has an
option which tells it to not delete any of the intermediate
files.  Use this, then try and see what is going on in the
assember files at these lines.  (When you ask g++ to output
assembler, it puts nice comments in to help finding the
corresponding source.  I don't know if it also does this when
generating assembler as an intermediate file.)  And then try
cutting code (if worse comes to worse, using binary search)
until you can get the error for a program of one or two lines.
Try to guess what's special about them, and change them to do
the same thing, in a different way.

And don't fail to report the error to g++.

Comment: Right, unless there is some funky inline assembly in use (there the programmer can write whatever junk they want).

Comment: James Kanze, that's it, I solved it by using your recommendation. I'll post solution ASAP

Comment: James Kanze, please take a look at my answer, maybe you know the answer to the 2nd question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to James Kanze's recommendation, I decided to tell to the compiler not to delete temporary files. This is done by the flag:

> -save-temps

As James said, the assembler generates some nice comments which inform exactly which line on our C++ code is throwing the error. In my case, it looks like it is not accepting such instruction:

```
asm
(
    ".intel_syntax noprefix\n"
    "lock dec [DWORD PTR eax]\n"
    ".att_syntax \n"
    :
    : "a" (data)
    :
);
```

I don't know why he is not accepting Intel Syntax anymore, since it was working with previous GCC version, and now that I updated it it doesn't anymore.

Anyway, the solution for such problems is the one mentioned by James: Just dont delete intermediate files so that you can spy directly into Assembly code what's wrong.

About the problem of the INTEL syntax, any idea why it doesn't work anymore?