# Why is this line of assembly an 'invalid use of register'?

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-mapping

I am going through some OS development tutorials and I constantly see the following section of code:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

do_e820:
    xor ebx, ebx        # ebx must be 0 to start
    xor bp, bp      # keep an entry count in bp
    mov edx, 0x0534D4150    # Place "SMAP" into edx
    mov eax, 0xe820
    mov [es:di + 20], dword 1   # <<<this is the line I don't get
    mov ecx, 24     # ask for 24 bytes
    int 0x15
    jc short .failed    # carry set on first call means "unsupported function"
    mov edx, 0x0534D4150    # Some BIOSes apparently trash this register?
    cmp eax, edx        # on success, eax must have been reset to "SMAP"
    jne short .failed
    test ebx, ebx       # ebx = 0 implies list is only 1 entry long (worthless)
    je short .failed
    jmp short .jmpin
```

When I try to assemble this for my home-rolled kernel, the assembler complains `Error: invalid use of register` at the line I have marked. If it helps understand the situation, I am using an gcc i686-elf cross assembler.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15066898

Comment: @Ira Baxter, I meant for, I've updated the question for clarification.

Comment: You should remove the Memory-mapping tag.  You have a problem with the assembler, not a problem with memory-mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of 16-bit registers inside otherwise 32 bit code suggests this is a snippet of ancient "magic" code, passed on from father to son in eldritch rituals. During that time, the supported syntax of *assemblers* changed, and so this once perfectly valid line is no longer accepted by the modern assembler you are using.

This line

```
mov [es:di + 20], dword 1
```

is more commonly written as

```
mov dword ptr es:[di + 20], 1
```

which is the notation used by Intel in their manuals.

Comment: Thanks for the the helpful answer. I'm marking yours as accepted, but I'd like to note that even the second version (which I had also tried since that is the notation I found in one of the PDF manuals) is also rejected as a valid instruction.

Comment: @JacobCalvert: thanks for trying that as well! I've deleted that suggestion, so only the currently modern one remains.